# unable to draw on multiple canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How to load multiple canvas and enable drawing on it. Currently, It shows two canvas on my page but I can only draw in one canvas.
I have two records in database. `foreach` loop below make two canvas but I can only draw in only one canvas not on the both canvas. I should able to draw on both canvas and that is the things I want. I am looking for any help or any tips on  how should I do so that I can draw on all canvas generated dynamically.

```
 <body onload="init()">
    
        <canvas  id="can_{{$draw->id}}" width="1200" height="400" 
            style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;">
        </canvas>
        
       
    </body>
```

Below is the js code that allows user to draw on image of canvas

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;
    
    var x = "red",
        y = 2;
    
    function init() {
for(let i=1;i<3;i++){
        canvas = document.getElementById('can_'+i);
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;
        //
       
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e){
            findxy('move', e)
          
            
    
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    
      
    }//end of for
    }
    
    function draw() {
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
      
    
    function findxy(res, e) {
    
        
        if (res == 'down') {
            
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                currY = e.clientY -canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                draw();
    
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: what are the ID of those canvas that you are injecting in the backend

Comment: {{$draw->id}} in loop gives id 1 and 2

Comment: Possibly because you only have one context you are drawing too. `ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");` I think this overwrites one as you are trying to assign one variable to two canvases. Maybe assign a ctx1 and ctx2 and see if that does it.

Comment: do you mean ctx1 = canvas.getContext("2d"); and  ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d"); in init()function. If i do this i think i have to write must of the function double for example draw() function one having ctx1 and another having ctx2

Comment: I added an answer with an option you can try

Comment: It seems there is a confusion about what you are willing to do: do you want both canvases to represent the same drawing, or do you want two independent drawing-boards? I feel this boils down to a misunderstanding of how closures work.

Comment: Hi, independent drawing

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this. Add the context to an array and see if you can draw to both. Not exactly sure the context thing is your problem but I think it is.

```js
let canvas1 = document.getElementById("c1");
let canvas2 = document.getElementById("c2");
let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
let ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

let ctx = [ctx1, ctx2];

function draw() {
  ctx.forEach((ctx, i) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100)
  });
}
draw()
```

```html
<canvas id='c1'></canvas>
<canvas id='c2'></canvas>
```

Adding what @Kaiido said for performance

```js
let canvas1 = document.getElementById("c1");
let canvas2 = document.getElementById("c2");
let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
let ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

ctx1.fillStyle = "lightblue";
ctx1.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100)

ctx2.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0)
```

```html
<canvas id='c1'></canvas>
<canvas id='c2'></canvas>
```

Comment: If they really want to draw the same thing on both contexts it would be a lot better to perform it only once and then just `drawImage` the updated canvas over the other one, rather than duplicating the drawing commands. But I don't think it's what they actually want. As I understand it, they want two independent drawing-boards.

Comment: @Kaiido I get what you're saying. I added an example of that.

Comment: But better reading their question I feel that at the end they only missed that `canvas` gets replaced in the loop and that their `findXY` call won't get the correct canvas. They should rewrite it all to make it more OOP and that each drawing-board is its own instance holding its own variables. If you've got time to teach them how to do so... I don't  ;-p

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that makes use of the fact we know which canvas generated a mouse event. Since we know that, we can use it to get the context of the correct canvas.

I show a message for mousemove and mousedown, indicating which canvas triggered the event.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";

   var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevx = 0,
        curx = 0,
        prevy = 0,
        cury = 0,
        dot_flag = false;
    
    var x = "red",
        y = 2;

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    let canvasElems = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
    canvasElems.forEach( 
                         can => {
                            can.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){ findxy('move', evt, this);}, false);
                            can.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt){ findxy('down', evt, this);}, false);
                            can.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt){ findxy('up', evt, this);}, false);
                            can.addEventListener('mouseout', function(evt){ findxy('out', evt, this);}, false);
                         } );
}

function findxy(reason, evt, elem)
{
    if (reason=='up' || reason=='out')
        flag = false;
        
    if (reason == 'down')
    {
        document.querySelector('#output').textContent = elem.getAttribute('name') + ' was clicked';

        prevx = curx;
        prevy = cury;
        curx = evt.clientX - elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        cury = evt.clientY - elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        //if (dot_flag) 
        //{
                let ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(curx, cury, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
        //}
    }
    else if (reason == 'move')
    {
        document.querySelector('#output').textContent = elem.getAttribute('name') + ' was moved over';
        if (flag)
        {
            prevx = curx;
            prevy = cury;
            curx = evt.clientX - elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            cury = evt.clientY - elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            draw(elem);
        }
    }
}

function draw(tgtCanvas) 
{
    let ctx = tgtCanvas.getContext('2d');
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevx, prevy);
    ctx.lineTo(curx, cury);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
</script>
<style>
canvas
{
    margin: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #333;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas name='canvas1'></canvas><canvas name='canvas2'></canvas>
    </br>
    <span id='output'></span>
</body>
</html>
```